# get date from R object

Tags: r

I have an object `stk` resulting from a `getYahooData` function call with the following properties:

`class(stk)` gives

```
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

`stk[1]` gives

```
            Open  High   Low Close  Volume    logret
1950-02-28 17.22 17.22 17.22 17.22 1310000 0.9921295
```

How do I get just the date, 1950-02-28?

`stk[1]$Date` gives

```
NULL
```

How do I get just the Open, 17.22?

`stk[1]$Open` gives

```
            Open
1950-02-28 17.22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates are the indices (something similar to rownames) and not part of the `Open` column.

Use the `index` function to extract them:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')

head(sample.xts)
#               Open     High      Low    Close
#2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
#2007-01-03 50.23050 50.42188 50.23050 50.39767
#2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236
#2007-01-05 50.37347 50.37347 50.22103 50.33459
#2007-01-06 50.24433 50.24433 50.11121 50.18112
#2007-01-07 50.13211 50.21561 49.99185 49.99185

index(sample.xts)[1]
#[1] "2007-01-02 CET"
```

A column is still an `xts` object:

```
class(sample.xts$Open)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

You can turn it into an atomic vector:

```
as.vector(sample.xts$Open)[1:5]
#[1] 50.03978 50.23050 50.42096 50.37347 50.24433
```